# ImageStoreService IdleSecondary replica

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a Service Fabric cluster with 5 nodes deployed to Azure. A few days ago one of the nodes in the cluster is failing to start the ImageStoreService and I'm seeing the following error:

> Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RAP', Property='IReplicator.BuildReplica(131347642528671415)Duration', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
>   The api IReplicator.BuildReplica(131347642528671415) on node _backend_0 is stuck. Start Time (UTC): 2018-07-19 12:47:20.764.

I have tried rebooting the virtual machine but it still remains in this state. It looks like it's currently in the `InBuild` replica state but I don't know what to look for or how to resolve it.

**Edit**

I logged into the virtual machine that is failing and looked at the Event Log for Service Fabric. I see tons of warning messages in the logs that look like this:

> CopyFile: no new token is found. current token count: 2

and a lot that have this:

> ImpersonateAndCopyFile for SourcePath:\10.10.10.1\StoreShare__node_3\131347742554673412\ApplicationName\ServiceName\Code\131347741584517844_1047972020224_30.File.dll, DestinationPath:C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SF_App__FabricSystem_App4294967295\work\Store\131347742554673413\ApplicationName\ServiceName\Code\131347741584517844_1047972020224_30.File.dll failed: E_ACCESSDENIED. Have tried all access tokens.

Seems like it is failing to either read or write the files. I'm not sure why.

Comment: This kind of issues is hard to answer without access to the cluster logs, maybe only the SF team will be able to help you, I would recommend you open a support ticket for this. This are some question your might have to answer: Is it a default cluster or you built it from a template? Did you upgrade the cluster recently? When you connect to the cluster, can you check if it is connected to the network and can find other nodes(ping)? Are the certificates up to date? Does the node show correctly in the SF Explorer? When you connect to the cluster, is the destination file being used by other svc

Comment: Can you try to update service [placement constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#node-properties-and-placement-constraints) to exclude this node? This should provoke SF to remove anything related to the service from this node. Then you again can revert placement constraints.

Comment: @OlegKarasik I'll try that thanks.

Comment: @Dismissile did you ever fix this? I'm seeing the same error